# Компилирование из готовых исходников взятых с github.com

Tags: vc++2015

Никогда не работал в vc++2015, решил перевести жестко закодированные строки плагина для Notepad++, все перевел что нужно и скомпилировал библиотеку DLL плагина. Плагин работает, все строки на русском языке. Но размер  файла библиотеки DLL в три раза больше размера от оригинального. Но оригинальный не был сжат в UPX или другом упаковщике. Господа не судите строго!

Comment: Проверить Release/debug?

Comment: KoVadim ...а подробней можно подсказать

Comment: если собираете в режиме debug, то оно точно больше будет. Плюс есть статическая/динамическая линковка. Если размер не мешает и все работает, то пусть себе работает.

Comment: Я никакие настройки в vc++2015 не менял, сделал перевод на русский язык и нажал собрать проект

Comment: Если вам не трудно подскажите как собрать проект с меньшим размером.

Comment: Давайте ссылку на проект.

Comment: https://github.com/ffes/nppsnippets/releases/tag/v1.4.0

Comment: Основные переводимые строки в файле NppSnippets_res.rc, и как это окно можно запустить в vc++2015 что проверить как оно выглядит?

Comment: В диспетчере конфигураций переключил на "Release" и размер выходного файла сразу похудел в три раза.